# Indent content in richtext field in xPages

Tags: dojo, ckeditor, xpages, rich-text-editor, xpages-extlib

My users want to indent the content in a richText field. I tried with CkEditor but it doesn't work. When I save the document, the identation dissapear. 
I added a spaces for tab key (config.tabSpaces = 4) but this no satisfies the users because this is not a real identation.
Then I tried use RichText dojo field. It seems that works fine but when I print the document, prints the lines of the "blockquote".

Somebody know any solution??

Thank you!!

Comment: Speak after me: there is no RichText in the Internet. It's HTML. HTML doesn't count spaces. If you want to create something like a block quote, use a CSS style with margin-left.

Comment: we store 'formatted text' in our as HTML in our Cloudant database and that goes very well. So go the HTML route as Stephan is mentioning and end up with css

Comment: Thanks for your answers.

but I have another problem. The users copy & paste text from M.Word, and when they do that, the formated text is lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Default, any Input entered through XPages that can have nasty/malicious code embedded (e.g. html / javascript) is run through an ACF (Active Content Filter)

This happens *server-side* in the XPages runtime. (You may notice CKEditor itself has this functionality too, but in the case of XPages, CKEditor does **not** do the filtering, it is performed server-side in IBM's ACF system.)

Some more information [available here](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.0/com.ibm.designer.domino.ui.doc/wpd_forms_xpages_security.html)

For some reason, the default filtering rules also filter out the 'margin' style attribute. This means when you users submit indented text, the margin is stripped out server side before saving  to the document.

If you set your htlmFilterIn="identity" then your system will no longer do any filtering and the margin will be preserved. However, your system is now vulnerable.

Another idea is to supply a custom set of rules in which the margin is not stripped out. Details of doing this are in the Mastering XPages book. but you basically take the acf-config.xml.sample in /properties directory, and rename it to acf-config.xml and then modify. (this will do it server-wide)

Comment: It works fine but finally we have to set two properties: as you said  htlmFilterIn="identity" and  htlmFilter="identity". Tks!!. ;-)